# Does every deterministic dynamic population (or probability) density implement replicator dynamics?

Tags: stochastic-processes, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems

(Used to ask: How to check whether a population density obeys replicator dynamics, but now I think I found a proof that the answer is that it does, except if some species have density zero).

Say we have a probability vector or population density $p = (p_1,...,p_n)$ with $p_i \geq 0$ and $\sum_i p_i =1$. Also assume we know the functions $g=(g_1,...,g_n)$ such that:

$$p_i(t+1) = g_i(p(t))$$

where $t$ is a discrete time index. Assume we want to know whether $g$ implements a discrete time replicator equation. I.e. whether there is a function $f=(f_1,...,f_n)$, called the *fitness landscape*, such that:

$$p_i(t+1)= \frac{f_i(p(t))}{\langle f \rangle_{p(t)}} p_i(t).$$

where $\langle f \rangle_{p(t)}:=\sum_j p_j(t) f_j(p(t))$ is the average fitness of the population density.

I'll now present the argument why the answer is yes at least as long as $p_i > 0$ for all $i$ and not just $p_i \geq 0$.

Since the left hand sides of the two equations are equal we get:

$$g_i(p(t)) = \frac{f_i(p(t))}{\langle f \rangle_{p(t)}} p_i(t).$$

Let's drop the time dependence since it is irrelevant here:

$$g_i(p) = \frac{f_i(p)}{\langle f \rangle_{p}} p_i$$

and solve for $f_i(p)$:

$$f_i(p) = \langle f \rangle_{p} \frac{g_i(p)}{p_i}$$

where we divided by $p_i$ so this only works if $p_i>0$. So, if for any $p$ such that there exists $j$ with $p_j=0$ we have $g_i(p)>0$ for some $i$ then we cannot write $g(p)$ as a replicator equation.
Else, we are basically done. To verify the solution let's start from the replicator equation and plug in the above:

\begin{align}
 \frac{f_i(p)}{\langle f \rangle_{p}} p_i &= \frac{f_i(p)}{\sum_j p_j f_j(p)} p_i \\
&=\frac{\langle f \rangle_{p} \frac{g_i(p)}{p_i}}{\sum_j p_j \langle f \rangle_{p} \frac{g_j(p)}{p_j}} p_i \\
&=\frac{\langle f \rangle_{p} \, g_i(p)}{\langle f \rangle_{p} \sum_j  g_j(p)}\\
&=\frac{g_i(p)}{\sum_j  g_j(p)}\\
&=g_i(p).
\end{align}
where we used $\sum_j  g_j(p)=1$ since $p(t+1)$ is again normalized (probability or population) vector by assumption. We note that the expectation value $\langle f \rangle_{p}$ drops out so that we can choose it freely when constructing the fitness e.g. $\langle f \rangle_{p}:=1$.

Is there a mistake in here or is the replicator dynamic really that general? Basically any deterministic evolution of a probability (including any Markov chain) that maps probabilities that are zero to zero has a fitness function such that it implements replicator dynamics?

Comment: Can you explain why do you set $\langle f \rangle_{p}$ to $1$? I'm not sure that you can really do that since fitness is non-constant along the phase space.

Comment: Good, question, that is the part I am most unsure about. But the thing is that it cancels out in the calculation (from line three to line four in the longer calculation). So whatever it depends on (and it does depend on $p$ which is the population density and maybe an element of phase space if that is what you call phase space) it still cancels out. So let's say I set it to $p^2$ just for fun. The whole argument starting from "and solve for $f_i(p)$ would still go through.

Comment: It seems that you really can do that. The original system has form $\overline{p}_{i+1} = g_i (p)$ and $\sum_{j} g_j (p) \equiv 1$. Let's set $\tilde{f}_i = \frac{g_i(p)}{p_i}$. Then $\overline{p}_{i+1} = \tilde{f}_i(p) p_i$. Easy to check that $\sum_j p_i \tilde{f}_i(p) = \sum_j g_j \equiv 1$, hence we can freely write $$\overline{p}_{i+1} = \frac{\tilde{f}_i(p)}{\langle f \rangle_p} p_i.$$ And if $g_i(p) \equiv 0$ when $p_i = 0$, $\tilde{f}_i(p)$ is actually a nice function, although one time less differentiable than $g_i(p)$.

Comment: Nice, that is clearer than my own argumentation! Also, well done spotting the change in differentiability. I would consider this as an answer, if you post it. By the way, do you know a lot about replicator dynamics? I am quite new to this and find this result quite weird / deflating.